# No drive mounts when phone connect to computer through USB

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, android

The computer is a desktop PC running **Windows 10 N**. The phone is a Sony Xperia Z2 running CM 12.1 (and is rooted). When I connect them using a USB cable, the phone appears in the device manager but nothing shows up in my computer. I want to easily be able to transfer large files between the computer and phone without using the internet.

Connecting the phone to the computer used to work fine and I'm suspecting some software updated that broke something.

As suggested, I uninstalled the driver from Device Manager, and tried installing it again. I downloaded [this zip file](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-z2-driver/) from the Sony website, extracted, and followed the directions of [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pBQLVmab1M) to install the drives: in device manager added a legacy device, chose "have a disk", and selected `sa0111adb.inf`. This did not work. Now there are two drivers in device manager:

[image: two drivers]

I have a Windows 7 VM that is able to connect to phone and I can access the internal memory and SD card through it. However I tried another Windows 7 VM and it did not work.

Here are the settings on the phone

[image: screenshot from phone]

I also tried different USB ports to make sure. I don't think it can be a problem with the cable, since it still works with Windows 7 VM.

Even though Windows N doesn't come with the media packages, I have already installed them and it still doesn't work.

for KB 3133719

[image: package already installed]

for KB3099229

[image: not applicable]

**UPDATE:**
On the Windows 7 VM (which I can actually connect to) the driver is different than device manager.

[image: device manager]

[image: device manager]

[image: device manager]

Comment: Are you sure the connection mode as set on the phone is MTP? Because by default it is just set to charge (+ADB, if enabled).

Comment: Hmhm. In Device Manager, please select the ADB device (which is not relevant for file transfer) and switch to “By connection” view. Then expand all related devices and provide a screenshot. Also, please provide a screenshot of “This PC” (Explorer screen where drives are).

Comment: To expand on my previous comment: I want [something like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lnIar.png).

Comment: @DanielB I red on the XDA-developer forums to make storage accessible  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mohammadag.samsungusbmassstorageenabler&hl=en

Comment: No, Mass Storage is most likely *not* what you want. MTP is a different protocol. Please provide the screenshots I asked for.

Comment: @DanielB screen shot added. I have now fixed the problem using the app in the link above so it appears in This PC.

Comment: Why do you say MTP is a different protocol, different from what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46280/discussion-between-daniel-b-and-celeritas).

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve the problem myself, but having taken advice from various sources am unsure which steps are required to fix the problem. Here is what I advise. Keep in mind this is for Cyanogenmod, not stock Android.

1. As per David Woodword's answer, make sure the correct Windows Media Player Feature Pack's are installed: [Windows 10 (build 1511)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49919) and [Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (build 1607)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53356).
2. On the phone, under settings > developer options > revoke USB debugging authorizations
3. From [XDA-developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-lg-g3/help/cm-12-1-connect-to-pc-via-usb-t3119898) "download "usb mass storage enabler" form google play" and use it.
4. When the phone is connected to the computer through a USB cable, the notice in the status bar header appears "Connected as a media device / Touch for other USB options". Touch it and toggle the settings. For example check and uncheck MTP or change to Charge only and back. The first time I did this the app froze.
   [image: screen shot from phone]

Answer (score 1):

Since the phone works through the Windows 7 VM, I would suggest looking at the device manager in the VM and see what drivers are listed as in use on that system.

If the drivers are different then obviously we'd start with trying to get the same drivers loaded on the PC.  I suspect they will be different because the ADB drivers you installed are for use by the Android development debugger.  I doubt they would allow the MTP/PTP/file browsing to work.

If the drivers are the same then I would recommend completely uninstalling the current drivers in device manager.  And tell the uninstall process "Yes" when it asks if you want to remove the files (or whatever that prompt is that comes up afterwards - can't remember).  Then unplug and plug back in and see what Windows tries to install by default.

In short, I suspect you need to find the MTP/PTP drivers rather than the ADB drivers.

Comment: +1 for the MPT drivers. (Windows 10N ships without them).

Comment: @Hennes you reminded me this is Windows 10 N

Comment: I also use win10N (no need for media player). I have yet to get MPT working. There seems to be no sane (that is, just what is needed and without tons of bloatware) driver download.

Comment: @Hennes it used to work on Windows 10 N unless I'm remembering incorrectly and was before the 10 upgrade, but I don't think so.

Comment: I got a Samsung S5 on win10N. Never got it to work. I gave up and use an old laptop whenever I want to transfer files (mostly pictures) from or to the phone. Tempted to install a win7 VM just to need one less PC. Any other solution would be nice, which is the main reason I looked at this question.  *crosses fingers and hopes you get a good answer*

Comment: Wait, as per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions), the "N" designation is just the European version.  There is still distinction between Home, Pro, Enterprise, and Education.  What version are you guys actually running?

Comment: Disregard.  Please see my [new answer](http://superuser.com/a/1130963/644647) - it looks like this has been covered before.

Comment: Apparently that still didn't fix your issue.  Sorry to hear that.  Is the same driver installed in both the Windows 7 VM and the Windows 10 host machine (looking under device manager - checking the driver version if the names are the same)?

Comment: @Hennes see the answer I have added

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [duplicate of another question](https://superuser.com/a/960788/644647) that has a well accepted answer that involves installing the Windows Media Player Feature Pack (which is not shipped with the N versions of Windows). But, I can't flag the question as a duplicate with an open bounty.

Links to download the Windows Media Player Feature Pack:

- [Windows 10 (build 1511)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49919)
- [Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (build 1607)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53356)

Comment: Tried and didn't work. First said package already installed, second said package not applicable to this computer.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Is the same driver installed in both the Windows 7 VM and the Windows 10 host machine (looking under device manager - checking the driver version if the names are the same)?

Comment: Also, please be certain you selected the appropriate architecture when you downloaded the patch (x86 or x64).  This could potentially cause the error you're seeing with KB3099229.

Comment: Confirmed, x64 architecture was downloaded.

Comment: I added screen shots from device manager on Windows 7 VM. They are different than Win 10.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the actual files/versions under the "Driver Details" button in the working VM to see if you can figure out what driver version you need to try to obtain for the Windows 10 system.  (Though it's possible they could be different because there are separate drivers because of the different OS versions)

Comment: It seems to be working again on Windows 10. I do not understand why. It happened when I tried disconnecting it from Windows 7 through VMware, then it appeared in Windows 10. It definitely did not do this before. I think it was a setting on Android (and to reiterate, I'm running Cyangoenmod so it's not really Android). I will attempt to reboot devices to see if fix stays.

Comment: For me, the "solution" is, whenever the phone is connected to the computer you need to change the USB computer connection to something other than MTP then change it back. Also used the app USB Mass Storage Enabler.

Comment: I suspect that you're right about this being CyanogenMod specific.  I haven't had that issue.  Maybe you should answer your own question to help others out.  I'd upvote it. :)

Answer (score -1):

First remove the device and download the most current sony drivers from the manufacturers website. Install the drivers then try to plug in the device again.

If that doesn't work and you have Wi-Fi or if you can create a hotspot on your phone connect your PC to your phone over the hotspot. This will be much faster than Bluetooth or NFC.

I've used ES File Explorer recently to transfer about 20 gigs of data. It is a pretty slick program. Below is a link on how to set that up. 
https://www.cnet.com/how-to/share-files-between-android-and-windows-with-es-file-explorer/

Comment: You should quote and cite the relevant information from the link.  Be sure you provide specifics on how to solve the authors problem

Comment: I recommend no longer using ES File Explorer. It used to be good. Last I used it, it spammed notifications and became more bloated at an alarming rate.

Comment: @daniel b - This is true for the free version. Buy pro for $4.99.

Comment: Uninstalling and installing again from downloading inf files from Sony website, did not work.