# Xperia Companion not detecting my HTC One V

Tags: usb, backup, android, data-transfer

I've installed it on my old phone (HTC One V), new phone (Xperia XA1), and PC (Windows 10), connected them all via USB and WiFi, and started the app on all devices. Both phones have completed the extraction of my contacts etc., but my old phone doesn't do WiFi Direct, so I'm attempting to use USB to presumably move `M:\XperiaTransferTemp` into the Xperia Companion running on the PC. That won't detect the old phone, though:

[image: Xperia Companion]

It backed up my new phone just fine, but how can it/I import the data it extracted on the old phone's Android 4.0.3? I can see it in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Its possible the HTC one V is just too old for the application to support it.

Comment: Then the app should tell me so instead of acting just like it does on my new phone.

Comment: Well, its not detecting it. Also, is the HTC on charging or MTP mode?

Comment: PC version says to use MTP if available, but it is set to transfer files, as stated i see the files in `M:\XperiaTransferTemp` on the PC.

Comment: As the companion log says "MSC: Failed to extract device root path" i guess it's confused about the internal storage and SD card being mounted as separate drives.

Comment: Indeed the Xperia Transfer app supports Android 4.0 as source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my old phone does support Wi-Fi Direct so it should be possible to bypass the PC app.

1. NEW PHONE: Settings > Backup & reset > Xperia Transfer Mobile > Previous device: Android > Wi-Fi Direct > Receive > Next
2. OLD PHONE: Settings > More > Wi-Fi Direct (enable) > Wi-Fi Direct settings > 'Xperia (listed under "Available devices"; above that is the old phone name) > Button or Pin code > Connect
3. NEW PHONE: Accept invitation or enter the WPS pin code. It now says "Step 5/6. Preparing for transfer. Nearly there..."

I'll leave them overnight, but the lack of a progress indicator is worrying... Indeed. Even after after restarting the Transfer app on the old phone, it says again that only transfer via a computer is supported. ([Which might be broken.](https://superuser.com/questions/950405/windows-10-is-unable-to-load-android-devices-as-mtp-devices))

I'll look for an alternative.

Old phone:

1. Export data using Xperia Transfer app.
2. Settings, Storage, Disconnect SD card.
3. Try to get your SD card to work again. (Before use, always [verify](https://www.instructables.com/id/Identifying-fake-SD-card-and-USB-sticks/) their [capacity](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/test-and-detect-fake-or-counterfeit-usb-flash-drives-bought-from-ebay-with-h2testw/).)